# What is the standard in returning the property objects when they are null in a REST API call?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I've implemented a Web API service which returns a list of Products.

The Product object has another property called A which is a class.

When the value of this A node is null, by default it's returning the below node in xml:

```
<A i:nil="true" />
```

My question is what is the standard in returning the property objects when they are null?

Is it the standard to hide the node or let it be returned with the above null representation?

Comment: In addition to Cuong Le's answer you may want to look at [Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: yeah, that's the way to do it when using xml Serialization but my question was not about how to remove it.